# Can I programmatically apply Angular validation directives inside a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found great many occurrences of the following pattern for html inputs, this being for phone numbers:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="CellPhoneNumber" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" ng-minlength="10" />
```

I would like to create a custom directive that, wherever applied, will tell Angular to apply all three of these rules, e.g:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="CellPhoneNumber" bk-ng-validation="phoneNumber"/>
```

Then, code in my directive would find and invoke a function called `phoneNumber`, in which I would like to see something like:

**Listing 1:**

```
function bkNgPhoneNumber(model) {
    // This is purely SPECULATIVE pseudo-code, just to convey an idea.
    model.errors.add(applyMinLength(10, model));
    model.errors.add(applyMaxLength(15, model));
    model.errors.add(applyPattern("/^[0-9]+$/", model));
}
```

I would prefer the above approach over 'rewriting code for these rules, e.g:

**Listing 2:**

```
function phoneNumber(model) {
    if (model.length < 10 || model.length > 15) {
        model.errors.add("Must be 10 to 15 chars!");
    }
}
```

I don't want to do away with all attribute based directives, but preferably create a 'macro' directive that will invoke my Listing 1 code, which will intern invoke a set of more 'micro' validations.

Comment: Simple directive to use as template seems all you would need for this with no other logic needed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do this (i.e. apply existing validators without writing their code again) would be to add the validation directives' respective attributes and force a re-compile. This would require your directive to have a high-enough priority and also be `terminal: true`.

```
app.directive("bkNgValidation", function($compile){
  return {
    priority: 10000,
    terminal: true,
    link: function(scope, element){
      element.attr("ng-required", "true");
      element.attr("ng-minlength", 20);
      element.attr("ng-maxlength", 30);

      // prevent infinite loop
      element.removeAttr("bk-ng-validation");

      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SG0Y4BwbNxtibzFx5dms?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for this novel approach. It had fleetingly crossed my mind to do something like this with jQuery, but I gave it no further thought because I'd rather not use jQuery and break something. Now I see how to do it 'pure angular;.

Comment: I have read a great deal of advice here that this is not the best way to achieve my eventual goal, but this answer is the most accurate for the specific instance I ask the question in context of, and it is working great.

Comment: @ProfK, I agree, it is not the most elegant way - there could be better ways to approach this issue, depending on whether you need to run your own validators vs. built-in, depending on how you plan to apply this directive, etc... It would have been better if you spent more time describing what your eventual goal was.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using more validations, you can create a service that is responsible for identifying and validating the elements, without any limitation. Default directives of angular remain.

Example:

```
    module.service('$Validation', ["$compile",function($compile){

        this.validators = {
            'phoneNumber': [['required', 1], ['minlength',6], ['maxlength', 10], ['pattern', /^[0-9]+$/.source]],
            'phoneNumber2Custom': function(value){ 
                return /^[0-9]{6,10}$/.test(value) 
            },
            'userTwitter': function(value){
                return /^@(.+)/.test(value)
            }
            // ...etc... /
        }

        this.add = function(scope, element, attrs, model){
            var name = attrs.bkNgValidation, type;
            if(!(type = this.validators[name])) return;
            else if(angular.isFunction(type)) return (model.$validators[name] = type);

            element.removeAttr("bk-ng-validation");
            angular.forEach(type, function(expr){
                element.attr(expr[0], expr[1])
            });
            $compile(element)(scope)        
        };

    }]).directive('bkNgValidation', ["$Validation", function ($Validation) {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            priority: 1e5,
            link: function(){
                $Validation.add.apply($Validation, arguments);
            }
        }
    }])
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4py7rhjRKVKYcwJgi3wL?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach:

```
.directive('bkNgValidation', function () {
  return: {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      if (attrs['bk-ng-validation'] === 'phoneNumber') {
       element.$validateModel(function (value, validator) {
         if (value.length < 10 || value.length > 15) {
           validator.$setValidity('phone', true);
         } else {
           validator.$setValidity('phone', false);
         }
       });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @ProfK alternatively, you can do no custom validation: `validator.$setValidity('ngMinLength', true); validator.$setValidity('ngMaxLength', true);`

Comment: Thanks. This is actually very close to my ultimate ideal, where instead of `if (attrs['bk-ng-validation'] === 'phoneNumber')`, I would use `callFunction('phoneNumber')`, where that function is in a controller or master view model, and keep the UI logic, i.e. the directive, and the business logic,i.e the validation, separate.

Comment: OK, but in your "no custom validation" suggestion, e.g. `validator.$setValidity('ngMinLength', true);`, where does `ngMinLength` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new component which including control with all required validators. Your component would look like:

```
<my-control name="field" ng-model="text"></my-control>
```

All required logic component should keep inside. To do it, create the `my-control` directive with template. Inside the template you can place an input with validation attributes:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" class="form-control" ng-pattern="'^(?!ng-*)'" minlength="3">
```

Then you need to bind ng-model value on your component to input:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('myControl', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       require: 'ngModel', //import ngModel into linking function
       templateUrl: 'myControl.tpl',
       scope: {}, //our component can have private properties, isolate it
       link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
           // reflect model changes via js
           ngModel.$render = function() {
               scope.value = ngModel.$viewValue;
           };
           // update model value after changes in input
           scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
               ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
           });
       }
   };
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/lovudonihe/1/edit?html,js,output) when you can see this component in action and how it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic stuff for a novice like me, and I can't wait to use it, but in the context I am working in now, I would rather keep the actual input element without change and just stick the validation on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the opposite way, because you are assuming that directives are that much laborious to maintain and want to keep one to give all the validation you need, depending on the element.

That's an interesting approach but you need to be warned about the modularity of this approach: give this much of labour to one directive only is counterintuitive over the best practices of doing a "pure Angular way" to do the things.

If you want to proceed with this idea, I suggest you to look over the `ngModelController` ([AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators)) properties, that can be injected on `link()` function of one directive. More precisely, the `$validators`.

You can add how many `$validators` to a NgModel controller you want.

During your validation, you can set/unset validity to the element returning a boolean:

```
app.directive('validator', function () {
    var definition = {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // Return if no ngModelController
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }

            ngModel.$validators.validateLength = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                // modelValue === the value of the ngModel, on the script side
                // viewValue === the value of the ngModel, on the HTML (rendered) side
                // 
                // you can set-up $parsers, $formatters, $validators, etc, to handle the element

                return !(modelValue.length > 20);
            }
        }
    };

    return definition;
});
```

I suggest you to read more about this implementation because certain operations can interrupt the flux of `$digest` cycles on angular over the manipulated element.

## Edit 1:

Like I've mentioned on the comments, here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mS9PQGb28SzVsGdG1uUL?p=preview) with an working example.

Comment: Thanks. It is always great to learn more of the 'right' way to do things, vs. my immediate 'quick and dirty'.

Comment: You welcome. The quick way can be very tempting, but can lead us to a big mess on a long term, with serious problems to deal with. Do you got the idea with my suggestion? Need more ideas?

Comment: I'll need to get your idea into code to get the feel for it, but looks good. I will definitely need more ideas, and so many more angular questions coming up here from me.

Comment: I'll provide one example and place on my answer.

Comment: The Plunkr is there. Remembering that this approach isn't the conventional way to do validation in Angular. The better way is to **provide one directive to do, whithout transferring `DOM` manipulation to controllers**.