# How should I package plugin functions for use in a validation directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, revealing-module-pattern

I am working on the below validation directive, suggested to me in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199855/8741):

```
MyBigAngularApp.directive("bkNgValidation", function ($compile) {
    return {
        priority: 10000,
        terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var validationType = attrs.bkNgValidation;
            window["addValidationFor_" + validationType](element);

            // prevent infinite loop
            element.removeAttr("bk-ng-validation");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Then, when I apply this directive to an html element, in the form, `bk-ng-validation="phoneNumber"`, my directive invokes this function:

```
function addValidationFor_phoneNumber(element) {
    element.attr("ng-pattern", "/^[0-9]+$/");
    element.attr("ng-minlength", 5);
    element.attr("ng-maxlength", 8);
    alert("yeah baby");
}
```

This `addValidationFor_phoneNumber` is currently in the global namespace, just for my proof of concept, but I am looking to maybe use a revealing module to organize what could become quite a number of validation functions. Or is there some other pattern I should follow because I am working inside Angular? I suspect I could do something like declare a constant for the revealing module and inject it into the directive, but I thought I'd ask this question before going too far down the wrong road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is generally not recommended to use variables from the global scope in Javascript, and an absolute anti-pattern when working with AngularJS.

What you are looking for is a `service` (or `factory`, which does the same job in a slightly different syntax), which would be injected to your directive.

```
MyBigAngularApp.service('bkService', function() {
  this.phoneNumber   = function(element) { ... }
  this.somethingElse = function(element) { ... }
});
```

And your directive becomes:

```
// Note how bkService is injected to the directive in this first line
MyBigAngularApp.directive("bkNgValidation", function ($compile, bkService) {
  return {
    priority: 10000,
    terminal: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var validationType = attrs.bkNgValidation;
        bkService[validationType](element);

        // prevent infinite loop
        element.removeAttr("bk-ng-validation");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

---

Now if the only directive that will use this service is that one, you don't really need to create a service but can simply wrap all these functions as private methods from bkNgValidation:

```
MyBigAngularApp.directive("bkNgValidation", function ($compile) {

  var validations = {
    phoneNumber:   function(element) { ... }
    somethingElse: function(element) { ... }
  };

  return {
    priority: 10000,
    terminal: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var validationType = attrs.bkNgValidation;
        validations[validationType](element);

        // prevent infinite loop
        element.removeAttr("bk-ng-validation");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer for a noob (me, not you). I really like the service idea, to separate concerns of linking an element to a function, i.e. the directive, and fulfilling that function, i.e the  service, but just for now, just this once, I'm going with the private methods approach, to limit my foray into the angular space.

Comment: Yep services become really useful as soon as you need to share information between two directives at least. But then if they have a strong hierarchy (ie dir2 is always inside dir1) some binding or inheritance methods are to be preffered, you may face these cases later on if you keep using that great framework :)